# Dynamic linear layout logic for given below image

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In my application, I need to design layout like given in a picture. The portion in red which have 3 views with green circle which will be dynamic. It can be 2 or 3 or 4 as I said it is dynamic. So please help to make logic of that or please suggest me how can I do that

[image]

Comment: better to use `GridView`.

Comment: actually the element in green circle comes one by one. So I don't know how to put it in gridview

Comment: http://androidexample.com/Custom_Grid_Layout_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=76&aaid=100

Comment: gridview is good option but it is under listview which generates scrolling problem and also I want to see complete list item(that are in green circle) without scrolling.

Answer (score 2):

Use the gridview or recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager with number of column 2.

Comment: this should be comment

Comment: Could you maybe give some more details or an example?

Comment: Who voted up?? This is not the way to answer. Please provide me any example or logic for that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use two `ListViews`

segregate your data so that even numbers go in the left `listview`, and odds in the right `listivew`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by creating TableLayout dynamically with some logic with arraylist in adapter.If anybody needs it I can also guide.

GridView is not the right solution because under listview it is not scrollable dut to parent scroll property.